# What was the business on Cato Neimoidia that Obi-Wan Kenobi referred to?

Tags: star-wars

After the rescue of the chancellor, Obi-Wan refutes Anakin's gloating of saving his life for the 10th time.

> ANAKIN: All right. But you owe me . . . and not for saving your skin for the tenth time . . .
>
> OBI-WAN: Ninth time . . . that business on Cato Neimoidia doesn't
>   count. I'll see you at the briefing.

Is there any information to the incident Obi-Wan was referring to?

Comment: And a question inspired by yours: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10649/what-were-the-other-8-times-that-anakin-saved-obi-wans-skin-before-rots

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[First Battle of Cato Neimoidia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Battle_of_Cato_Neimoidia)

Source: "Labyrinth of Evil" book.

From [starwars.com blog](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://blogs.starwars.com/UltimateStarDestroyer/10/comments&ei=8cwxT5LmDvS40AHl3OD6Bw&usg=AFQjCNELRPJVacOLxFPRSjDMVqXwjjfn2Q&sig2=MPD9CM2IQxnDEhqR6DOk2A), the following is the "save" description, neatly summarized:

> During on Cato Nemoidia, Obi-wan lost/dropped his rebreather and Anakin found it. Eventually Anakin gave it back to Obi-wan when he needed it. (According to my recollection, reading LoE last year)

And here are the relevant quotes from the book:

> On the fly he used the Force to call the thing to his left hand and realized that it was Obi-Wan's rebreather, which must have fallen from its utility pouch during the brief exchange with the unseen battle droids.
>   ...
>   While all this was occurring, something else was afoot. Strands of some gauzy white substance were beginning to drift from the holed shipping container. Obi-Wan realized instantly what the substance was.
>   Taking one hand from the hilt of lightsaber, he began to fumble for the rebreather pouched on his belt, only to find it empty. "Stars' end," he cursed, more in disappointment than anger. Already beginning to feel woozy.
>   ...
>   Anakin had his rebreather in his mouth as he approached the room in which Obi-Wan had held his own against better than fifty droids, all of which lay scattered about the room. A weaving, shuffling, staggering Obi-Wan was dealing with the last of them when Anakin entered. When the final droid collapsed, Obi-Wan aimed the blade of his lightsaber casually toward the floor and stood swaying in place, breathing hard but almost grinning.
>   "Anakin," he said happily. "How are you?" When Anakin went to him, Obi-Wan promptly collapsed in his arms. Anakin deactivated Obi-Wan's blade and inserted a rebreather into his mouth - - the same one that had ended up on the floor of the grotto.

Comment: So does mention in the movie make LoE canon in the Disneyverse?