# What were the OTHER 8 times that Anakin saved Obi-Wan's skin before ROTS?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

From Obi-Wan and Anakin's dialog in ROTS:

> ANAKIN: All right. But you owe me . . . and not for saving your skin for the tenth time . . .
>   OBI-WAN: Ninth time . . . that business on Cato Nemoidia doesn't count. I'll see you at the briefing.

**What were the OTHER 8 times that Anakin saved Obi-Wan's skin?**

Thanks to Jared's [last question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/what-was-the-business-on-cato-nemoidi-that-obi-wan-kenobi-referred-to) for giving me the impulse to ask this.

Comment: It's gotta be something Clone-wars–related, but not having watched that, I can't get more specific.

Comment: @Martha - be very interesting to see if any of the answers can be cross referenced to clone wars episodes.

Comment: Seems a very tough question... only a deal for those who have read all EU books...

Comment: @SachinShekhar - well, if it weren't for EU books, I wouldn't even be interested in SW that much

Comment: I could answer that but sadly would break the "fourth wall".

Comment: @Arc-Vile - you were correct to limit to comment - this question was explicitly "inside the walls" context wise. But if you have an interesting fact to address from outside the 4th wall, don't hesitate to add as a comment, and if it's sufficiently illuminating, the poster or another user might even commment indicating it's worth adding as a answer.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident

Answer (score 7):

Well this might not be what you're looking for exactly, but the short answer is that there aren't really exactly 8 other times. It's simply a line to show that they're friends working together, and to establish Anakin's character as someone who would try to keep count, it's a friendly jab. But I can at least give examples of many times Anakin has saved Obi-wan, any one of which may have been included in Anakin's remark:

- In the Battle of Ohma-D'un, Obi-wan is dueling with Asajj Ventress, Anakin, with the help of an ARC trooper, comes to Obi-wan's aid and helps him defeat Ventress.
- When Obi-Wan and ARC trooper Alpha-17 are held and tortured by Asajj Ventress, it is Anakin Skywalker and Ki-Adi-Mundi who rescue them.
- At the Battle of Christophsis, Obi-wan is taken captive. If Anakin hadn't destroyed the shield generator when they did, he may not have been able to take control of the situation.
- When Obi-wan is held in the Zygerrian Labour Processing Hub on Kadavo, it is Anakin who comes to rescue him.

I'm sure there are more in all of the EU material but those are what I could find right away.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a list largely compiled by [darkslayer of theforce.net](https://boards.theforce.net/threads/anakin-saving-obi-wan.50021664/#post-51684991), but edited by me to include that nest of Gundarks, to exclude the shields in the The Clone Wars film, because that was technically Ahsoka, and updated with the new canon source for that business on Cato Neimoidia,* which, in Legends, occurred in Labyrinth of Evil and involved a missing rebreather. The previous answer here was true at the time, but uses enough examples that are now Legends that, to my knowledge, there are only ten canon times.

1. That nest of Gundarks
2. AOTC: Anakin recovers from the Force Lightning and blocks Dooku's would-be fatal blow
3. Landing at Point Rain: Anakin and Ki-Adi-Mundi save Obi-Wan and his forces from the Geonosians.
4. Grievous Intrigue: Anakin rescues Obi-Wan and Adi Gallia from Grievous's ship.
5. The Citadel: Anakin deactivates the electrical field holding the rescue party's weapons (including Obi-Wan's).
6. Kidnapped: Anakin difuses the bombs around the Togruta village, allowing Obi-Wan to use the Force to beat up a Zygerian slaver.
7. Escape from Kadavo: Anakin and Plo Koon liberate Obi-Wan and the Togrutas from slavery.
8. The Lost One: In their fight with Dooku Anakin uses the Force to stop Obi-Wan from falling.
9. Old Friends Not Forgotten: That business on Cato Neimoidia.
10. ROTS: Anakin defeats Dooku and brings Obi-Wan along unconscious on his back.